# How are methods like ToString() from ValueType overriden in a plain struct?

Tags: c#

All the other value types (other than struct, ignore the nullable versions) use an extra struct (like `Int32`) or class (`Enum`) to override methods from `ValueType`. However, in the case of struct there is no such thing, because struct derives directly (and implicitly) from `ValueType`. Consequently, what is the mechanism to override the methods in `ValueType`?

For example, take `ToString()` run on a struct variable. Where is the code for `ToString()` specific to struct? The code seems to come from `ValueType` 
itself, e.g.

```
    public override String ToString()
    {
         return this.GetType().ToString();
    }
```

while `GetType()` is defined as "`extern`" (NET does not provide its source code). So instead of using the overrides based on class hierarchies, does C# use non-documented methods to get the info about a derived object, outside the object-oriented model?

Comment: Please be more specific what you want to know. Is it about practical overriding (I get the feeling you already know this), about the language definition for overriding in structs, about the CLR implementation or about  ???

Comment: I turned the final (true/false) statement into a question, as it looks like this is what you are asking about. Feel free to edit further, but please remember to finish on a question.

Comment: Which methods are you calling undocumented? Are you asking how to override base methods in a custom struct, or how the CLR implements such overrides? Your question would benefit from an edit to clarify.

Comment: The code for ToString() when run on a struct variable is not documented. Such struct does ***NOT*** provide its own override meaning either ValueType or Object() provides the code in its own ToString(). So how the base class can provide info about a derived object when it should be the other way around? Apparently, C# uses the extern GetType() to pull the info about a derived object through a back door which is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a virtual method call on a constrained type. The answer to this can be found in some [rather obscure smallprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained?view=netframework-4.7):

> When a callvirt method instruction has been prefixed by constrained thisType, the instruction is executed as follows:
>
> - ...
> - If thisType is a value type and thisType does not implement method then ptr is dereferenced, boxed, and passed as the 'this' pointer to the callvirt method instruction.
>
> This last case can occur only when method was defined on Object, ValueType, or Enum and not overridden by thisType. In this case, the boxing causes a copy of the original object to be made. However, because none of the methods of Object, ValueType, and Enum modify the state of the object, this fact cannot be detected.

In short, the magic happens because of [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

Comment: The main issue is ***NOT*** how the method is called on a struct. I provide ToString() as an example. This method is an override meaning that when you call it there will be no boxing because it will be called with "callvirt" and not with "box". The main issue is that the override is ***NOT*** provided by the struct itself but by ValueType or even by Object itself. So the main issue is how the code in a base class can provide info about a derived object when it should be the other way around?